# What is the parametric and cartesian equation of a hyperbolic paraboloid formed by the intersection of two cylinders of radius "A" & "B"?

Tags: algebraic-curves, parametric, hyperbolic-geometry

What is the parametric and cartesian equation of a hyperbolic paraboloid formed by the intersection of two cylinders of radius "A" & "B", which intersect at a distance of "H" from its Axis at an angle "Theta" ?

[image]